# Solution to the linear SDE $dX_t = \alpha X_t \, dt + \sqrt{2} dB_t$ using Itô calculus

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

So if I have the following generator and an initial condition:

$$A(f)(x) = \alpha x f'(x) + f''(x) \\ X_0 = x \in \mathbb{R}^+$$

I've been asked to find $X_t$ and assume that $\alpha$ is a constant.  From the definition of the infinitesimal generator, I get that:

$$dX_t = \alpha X_t dt + \sqrt{2} dB_t$$

How do I go about setting up an application of Ito's Lemma to this diffusion in order to solve for $X_t$?  Separation of variables doesn't seem to apply in this situation.

Comment: Sure that the definition of $A$ is correct? Usually, the generator is deterministic, i.e. $$Af(x) = a x f'(x) +f''(x).$$

Comment: Ah, no you are correct.  Thanks for catching.

Comment: But in the SDE it should read $X_t$ (... instead of $x$). Otherwise, it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Really?  Perhaps I've missed something then.  If $x$ is deterministic then why would $b(x)$ not be deterministic as well?  It has to be some function of a stochastic process?

Comment: If $(X_t)_t$ is a solution of the SDE $$dX_t = b(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dB_t$$ its generator equals $$Af(x)= b(x) f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x) f''(x).$$

Comment: Ok, I believe that I understand why this is now.  Thanks for the clarification.  Any thoughts on how to go about setting up the Ito calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve the SDE

$$dX_t = \alpha X_t \, dt + \sqrt{2} \, dB_t \qquad X_0 = x \tag{1}$$

we consider the corresponding ordinary differential equation

$$dx(t) = \alpha x(t) \, dt, \qquad x(0)=c.$$

It is not difficult to see that its unique solution equals

$$x(t) =  c \,  e^{\alpha t}.$$

Now the idea is to use an analogue of the variation of constants-approach: We let the constant $c$ depend on the time $t$ and on $\omega$, i.e. we set

$$C_t(\omega) := X_t(\omega) \cdot e^{-\alpha t}. \tag{2}$$

Applying Itô's formula (to $f(t,x) := x e^{-\alpha t}$), we get

$$C_t - C_0 = \int_0^t e^{-\alpha s} \, dX_s - \alpha \int_0^t X_s e^{-\alpha s} \, ds \stackrel{(1)}{=} \sqrt{2} \int_0^t e^{-\alpha s} \, dB_s.$$

Hence, by $(2)$,

$$X_t = C_t e^{\alpha t} = e^{\alpha t} C_0 + \sqrt{2} \int_0^t e^{\alpha (t-s)} \, dB_s.$$

Finally, note that

$$C_0 = X_0 \cdot 1 = x.$$

**Remarks**

1. The process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.
2. Another possibility to solve $(1)$ is the following: First solve the homogeneous SDE $$dX_t = \sqrt{2} \, dB_t$$ and then, using again an approach similar to variation of constants, find a solution to the non-homogeneous SDE $(1)$, see e.g. *René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the extremely thorough and clear answer!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Thanks...

Comment: Here's another way to think about this, which feels a little bit more systematic to me. Rewrite $dX_t - \alpha X_t dt = \sqrt{2} dB_t$ as $d ( \exp(-\alpha t) X_t ) = \sqrt{2} \exp(-\alpha t) dB_t$. Then the solution is $\exp(\alpha t) Y_t$ where $dY_t = \sqrt{2} \exp(-\alpha t) dB_t$ and $Y_0 = X_0$.

Comment: @Ian But that's exactly what I did in my answer.

Comment: As I said, it's the same procedure, just a different way of writing/thinking about it. Your way of looking at it is to adopt an ansatz: you assume a form of the solution and see what the result must be given this form. My way of looking at it modifies the equation instead. Of course the modification anticipates the ansatz, so they are very similar.