# How to solve $\mathop{dX_{t}} = \alpha X_{t} \mathop{dt} + \beta \mathop{dW_{t}}$ holds, where $X_{0} = x?$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm learning about stochastic processes, and I want to solve

$$\mathop{dX_{t}} = \alpha X_{t} \mathop{dt} + \beta \mathop{dW_{t}}$$
 where $X_{0} = x$.

I think that the solution uses Ito's Lemma; however, I am not too sure about how to get the answer. I also recognize this to be the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, and I think that the solution will be a diffusion process.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What is $X$? What do you think the relation holds for? Do you mean if OU processes satisfy the relation?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why I typed I want to show the relation holds. I do not want to show it holds. I want to solve it. I just edited the post to match my question

Comment: Okay now it makes more sense. I'll answer tomorrow if no one has answered by then :-)

Comment: Thanks! I will also try to keep solving the problem.

Comment: The SDE is a particular case of a so-called linear SDE, see the linked question and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813755/36150). If you search for "linear SDE" you will find several other questions which are related to yours.

Comment: Hint: using Ito Lemma calculate $d(e^{-\alpha t}X_t)$

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help. I outlined the answer to question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852453/solution-to-the-linear-sde-dx-t-alpha-x-t-dt-sqrt2-db-t-using-it%C3%B4-c to solve this problem, and I got $X_{t} = xe^{\alpha t} + \beta\int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha(t- s)} \mathop{dW_{s}}$ as my answer. Is this correct? Somebody told me that the $xe^{\alpha t}$ term that I currently am adding to the integral should be just $x$.

Comment: Your answer is correct. The exponential is from $X_t e^{-\alpha t} = x + \beta\int_0^t e^{-\alpha s}dW_s$. That somebody maybe confused by $e^0X_0$ from the integration.